# How many ways are there to get $x_1+x_2+...+x_8=60$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $x_1,...,x_8\in \{1,2,...,14\}$. How many ways are there to get $x_1+x_2+...+x_8=60$ such that the $x_i$ are distinct, i. e. $x_i\neq x_j$ if $i\neq j$. An example would be $3+2+4+5+7+12+13+14=60$.

Is this some stars and bars problem?

Comment: That seems hard...

Comment: Yes, you can use stars and bars with an upper constraint, or an ordinary generating function.

Comment: @trueblueanil slightly complicated by the $x_i$ needing to be "unique" (distinct?)

Comment: By "... each $x_i$ can have a *unique* value, do you mean that all the $8$ values have to be distinct ? Then, of course, it is a different kettle of fish !

Comment: Can you assume that $x_i < x_{i+1}$? I think that may help

Comment: Sorry, yes, they have to be distinct. That's what I mean. $x_i\neq x_j$ if $i\neq j$.

Comment: The restriction of distinctness is what makes this hard. Otherwise we could just consider the coefficient of $x^{60}$ in
$$
(x^1 + x^2 + \ldots + x^{14})^8
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the $x_i$ have to be distinct, this is $8!$ times the number of solutions to the partition problem $y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_8=60$ where $1 \le y_1 < y_2 <\cdots <y_8\le 14$

And, by letting $z_i=y_i - i$,  that is the number of solutions to $z_1+z_2+\cdots +z_8=24$ where $0 \le z_1 \le  z_2 \le \cdots \le z_8\le 6$

Your $3+2+4+5+7+12+13+14=60$ example would then be counted as one of the cases of $1+1+1+1+2+6+6+6=24$

The sub-problem is now a question of [doubly restricted partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partitions_in_a_rectangle_and_Gaussian_binomial_coefficients).  If $p(n,a,b)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into up to $a$ parts each no larger than $b$ then we can say $$p(n,a,b)=p(n,a,b-1)+p(n-b,a-1,b)$$ starting with $p(0,a,b)=1$.

I think this gives $p(24,8,6)=151$.  So the original question would have the answer $151 \times 8! = 6088320$.

Comment: Thanks! This is a problem that I faced when doing statistics. Your solution matches a histogram. It should have about 0.05 probability, and that would match since $(151\cdot 8!)/(8!\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 14\\8 \end{pmatrix})\approx 0.050283$. It's interesting that the $8!$ cancels.

Comment: The $8!$ cancelling is not a surprise; it related to the identical order transition from distinct partitions to distinct compositions and from permutations to combinations.  As for your matching statement, you have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ab} p(n,a,b) = {a+b \choose a}$